# $\lim_{z->0}(z)/(|z|)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$z$ is a complex number. I tried doing this by putting $z=x+iy$ in the equation and then trying to approach the limit by approaching the limit first on real axis and then on real axis.

Comment: That's the idea (more or less). $\frac z{\lvert z\rvert}$ is constant on every ray, and for each ray it is a different complex number of modulus $1$.

Comment: it would be easier to see this in polar coordinates

Comment: Consider the sequences $z_n=1/n$ and $z_n' = i/n$

Comment: Your method will work, why did you stop ?

Comment: yeah the limit does not exists as the values are not same.

Answer (score 1):

The limit does not exist. You can tell by looking at the real line. For $x>0$ it gives $1$, and for $x<0$ it gives $-1$.

More generally, you can look at rays of different angles: $z=r e^{i \theta}$, $z/|z|= e^{i\theta}$, which is constant on the ray, and therefore equals the limit on that ray. Thus every ray has a different limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x}{|x|}\ne\lim_{y\to0}\frac{iy}{|iy|}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x+iy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{1+im}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$ along $y=mx$